# Unable to connect cqlsh

Tags: cql, cassandra-3.0, cqlsh

Getting Error while connecting to cqlsh

bash-5.2# cassandra -v
3.11.5
bash-5.2# python --version
Python 3.11.8

bash-5.2# cqlsh --ssl --debug
Using CQL driver:
<module 'cassandra' from '/usr/share/java/cassandra/bin/../lib/cassandra-driver-internal-only-3.25.0.zip/cassandra-driver-3.25.0/cassandra/**init**.py'>
Using connect timeout: 5 seconds
Using 'utf-8' encoding
Using ssl: True
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'xx.xx.xx.xx:9042': PermissionError(1, "Tried connecting to [('xx.xxx.x.xx', 9042)]. Last error: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] ssl/tls alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1006)"), 'xx.xxx.xx.xxx:9042': PermissionError(1, "Tried connecting to [('xx.xxx.xx.xxx', 9042)]. Last error: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] ssl/tls alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1006)"), 'xx.xxx.x.xx:9042': PermissionError(1, "Tried connecting to [('xx.xxx.x.xx', 9042)]. Last error: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] ssl/tls alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1006)"), 'xx.xxx.xx.xx:9042': PermissionError(1, "Tried connecting to [('xx.xxx.xx.xx', 9042)]. Last error: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] ssl/tls alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:1006)")})

added version = SSLv23 parameter in cqlshrc. But still having the same issue.